# Sort the columns if the flag is true-orderby angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a table which is sorted on the `name` column by default.I want to enhance it to make that sorting behavior optional based on a `isSortingRequired` flag.How can i provide a conditional `orderby` clause in my template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
orderBy:(isSortingRequired?'CONDITION_FOR_SORT_REQUIRED':'CONDITION_FOR_SORT_NOT_REQUIRED')
```

When `''` is passed to an `orderby` filter it tries to sort by `hashkey` of the object this might create issues in the order of the records.The solution is to use a custom filter as defined below which uses the built in orderBy filter if the flag is true.

```
 .filter('customOrder',function($filter)
    {
        return function(friend, prediate,isSortRequired){
          if(!isSortRequired)
          return friend;
          else
          {
            var result = $filter("orderBy")(friend, prediate);
              return result;
          }

        }
    });
```

The solution can be seen [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Er48MQRut8KMT3yPTNPF?p=preview).This has fixed my issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ternary operator like

```
orderBy:(isSortingRequired?'CONDITION_FOR_SORT_REQUIRED':'CONDITION_FOR_SORT_NOT_REQUIRED')
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/a77cQ12VwKC3cKRZzeav?p=preview)

Comment: In demo plnkr I just displayed based on static flag. Check output by chagning it's value.

Comment: this just works fine if the number of rows is 10 if there are more than 10  records and the flag is false it just gives me a scrambled order.Demonstrated in this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/YZBTYCCdpl6fgUcmlz67?p=preview